# pfSense Port Forwarding using Alias Not Working

Tags: router, firewall, port-forwarding, nat, pfsense

I am running a pfSense 2-3-RELEASE firewall and I am trying to set up NAT port forwarding so some development servers and my Mac.   The servers (FreeBSD) have statically assigned IP's and my iMac has a dynamically assigned IP.

**The problem I have is with *Aliases***

When I set up port forwarding for HTTP, or SSH to the individual hosts and use an IP address as the destination host, it works just fine.  So, I know my firewall rules and NAT configuration are fully functional.  I also know that NAT reflection works because I can do this internally and eternally to my network.

What I want to do is use an *Alias* to reference the host using the FQDN:

[image]

If I test out (ping) both the FQDN and the Alias, it works.  The host responds with no issues.

However, when I reference the Alias in NAT Port Forwarding, it doesn't work; meaning it will not make the connection as it times out.

[image]

Now, using the IP address is not a major issue for me with the servers as their IP don't change at all, though I would like to use an Alias since it's easier to remember what the server is rather than look up an IP.  However, since my iMac is assigned a dynamic address, I would like to get this to work.

Is there something I am doing wrong in this config or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since aliases can contain multiple IP addresses or FQDNs, I don't believe you can use them as endpoints for static NATs.